# Where can I download poolmon.exe for Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, poolmon

I can only find the Windows XP version. I don't have the Windows Server 2003 cd handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the [**Windows 2003 Support Tools**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6EC50B78-8BE1-4E81-B3BE-4E7AC4F0912D&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the below mentioned link to download Windows Driver Kit which contains Poolmon.exe

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit